# PySide: Inconsistent file dialogs

Tags: qt, pyside, appearance, qfiledialog

I'm working on an application that requires saving and loading of files.

To load files, I'm using `QtGui.QFileDialog()`, and then calling `file_browser.exec_()`. That gives this result:

[image: screenshot1]

To save a file, I'm calling `file_browser.getSaveFileName()` which gives a completely different looking window:

[image: screenshot2]

Is there any way to make both of these windows look consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static functions like `getSaveFileName` will always use a *native* dialog, unless you include [`DontUseNativeDialog`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) in the options argument.

On the other hand, the `QFileDialog` constructor will always create an instance of Qt's built-in file dialog, no matter what options are set. You can change the [file-mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#FileMode-enum) to get the type of dialog you want.

Comment: I changed the save file dialogue to be `self.file_browser.getSaveFileName(options=QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)` and now it's consistent! It's a shame that there's no way to set them both to native, it looks much nicer that way.

Comment: @JoeShanahan You can get the open dialog to be native if you use getOpenFileName() instead of exec_().